# Radio values in text box on page load

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, radio-button

I'm wondering if anyone can help me, I'm trying to load the checked radio button value to the text box when the page is loaded?
Here's my HTML

```
<h2>Configuration</h2>
<div>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual" name="car" value="277790.00" checked="checked" >
<label for ="gtmanual">GT Manual -  &euro; 27,7790.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtauto" name="car" value="28,500.00" >
<label for ="gtauto">GT Automatic -  &euro; 28,500.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtsmanual" name="car" value="32,450.00">
<label for ="gtsmanual">GT-S Manual -  &euro; 32,450.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual" name="car" value="33,155.00">
<label for ="gtsauto">GT-S Auto -  &euro; 33,155.00 </label>
 <br>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" id="total" readonly>
</div>
</div>
```

And her is the javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load", getvalue, false);
function getvalue()
{

var rad = document.getElementsByName('car');
var value = null;
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function() {
    value=document.querySelector('input[name="car"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById('total').value=value ; 
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Please put it in a jsfiddle ...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this two lines available when body is being loaded, You are putting the value by script only when the radio button is clicked.

```
var value=document.querySelector('input[name="car"]:checked').value;
document.getElementById('total').value=value ;
```

Something like this.

```
window.addEventListener("load", getvalue, false);

//this would run when body is loaded
var value=document.querySelector('input[name="car"]:checked').value;
document.getElementById('total').value=value ; 

function getvalue(){
    var rad = document.getElementsByName('car');
    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        rad[i].onclick = function() {
            //this would run only when radio button is clicked
            value=document.querySelector('input[name="car"]:checked').value;
            document.getElementById('total').value=value ; 
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy7YE/2/)

Comment: Just out of interest, how would I go about adding the radio value thats selected to a global variable?

Comment: global variable `value` will be overided when user clicked on radio button.